Avalonia. Формат файла из примера
Склонировал с Git решение Avalonia, чтобы научиться работать с OpenGL в Авалонии, чтобы сделать простую зацикленную крутящуюся фигурку в программе на Avalonia. Собрал, запустил проект GpuInterop, всё работает, 3Д модель чайника крутится. Начал изучать. Сам чайник в файле teapot.bin в папке:
..\Avalonia\samples\ControlCatalog\Pages
Похоже, что это какой-то бинарный формат. Что конкретно это за формат? Чем можно открыть/редактировать? И как мне перевести свою модель в такой же формат? Например, из Блендера, например, из расширения .fbx или .obj.
Вот скриншот из шестнадцатеричного редактора с началом этого чайника:


Можете приложить скриншот из шестнадцатиречного редактора с началом этого bin чайника? Но вообще, подозреваю, что это какой-то свой ситуативный формат.

@Kromster добавил.

Похоже на минималистичный доморощенный формат. Заголовок 4 байта с числом элементов (0x00002520 - 9504штук (или 3168 по 3) вам о чем-то говорит?), потом идут числа с точкой (скорее всего вертексы), их видно по паттерну из 4 байт заканчивающемуся на 40 и C0. Поищите как он читается, скорее всего это просто массив вертексов треугольников, или 2 массива - вертексов и индексов.
